# Java Spring Rest validation configure property access

Tags: java, spring, maven, validation, hibernate-validator

I have a Spring-JSON/RestAPI that use annotation driven input validation. `@Valid`

I get the following error when I try to validate an object inside another object.

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: JSR-303 validated property 'client.application' does not have a corresponding accessor for Spring data binding - check your DataBinder's configuration (bean property versus direct field access)
    at org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.SpringValidatorAdapter.processConstraintViolations(SpringValidatorAdapter.java:153) ~[spring-context-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.SpringValidatorAdapter.validate(SpringValidatorAdapter.java:108) ~[spring-context-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.validation.DataBinder.validate(DataBinder.java:866) ~[spring-context-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    ...
```

Here is the json data model that is used here:

```
{ // @Valid MessageDTO
  "title": "Test",
  "message":"Test",
  "client": { // @Valid ClientDTO
    "application": "Test"
  }
}
```

I skip the java definition here since it would be too much useless noise IMO.

I don't want to/can't easily add getters or setters to my DTOs so how can I follow that error message and configure my DataBinder to use "direct field access"? I would like to use JavaConfig (`@Configuration`) for this.

Use use the following dependencies:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
    <version>4.3.2.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
    <version>5.2.4.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

EDIT:

Controller:

```
@RequestMapping(path = "/send", method = { RequestMethod.POST, RequestMethod.PUT })
public void send(@Valid @RequestBody MessageDTO message)
```

MessageDTO:

```
public class MessageDTO {

    ...

    @Valid
    @NotNull
    public ClientDTO client;

}
```

ClientDTO:

```
public class ClientDTO {

    ...

    @NotEmpty
    public String application;

}
```

Comment: At least the fields should be public, are they? you can anotate the fields?

Comment: I have added some of the sources. As you can see they are public. If I remove the `@Valid` from `MessageDTO#client` I won't get an Exception, but it won't get validated recursively either.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

I just stumbled upon the same issue and found a solution for us and just wanna to share it.

Within the Resource or a `@ControllerAdvice` you can configure the Spring DataBinder to use direct field access.

```
@ControllerAdvice    
public class CustomControllerAdvice {

    @InitBinder
    private void activateDirectFieldAccess(DataBinder dataBinder) {
        dataBinder.initDirectFieldAccess();
    }

    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I will test and verify your suggestion next week.

Comment: This is exactly the solution.

Comment: For some reasons it didn't help me https://stackoverflow.com/q/77404307/2674303

Answer (score 7):

For me, the solution was to add getters and setters to the DTO

```
public class MessageDTO {

    ...

    @Valid
    @NotNull
    public ClientDTO client;

    @NotNull public ClientDTO getClient() { return client; }
    public void setClient(@NotNull ClientDTO client) { this.client = client; }

}
```

Comment: Just the getters will do the job