# Spring Validate List of Strings for non empty elements

Tags: java, spring, validation, java-8, spring-validator

I have a model class which has list of Strings. The list can either be empty or have elements in it. If it has elements, those elements can not be empty. For an example suppose I have a class called QuestionPaper which has a list of questionIds each of which is a string.

```
class QuestionPaper{
private List<String> questionIds;
....
}
```

The paper can have zero or more questions. But if it has questions, the id values can not be empty strings. I am writing a micro service using SpringBoot, Hibernate, JPA and Java. How can I do this validation. Any help is appreciated.

For an example we need to reject the following json input from a user.

```
{ "examId": 1, "questionIds": [ "", " ", "10103" ] }
```

Is there any out of the box way of achieving this, or will I have to write a custom validator for this.

Comment: why don't you throw a  exception

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Custom validation annotation shouldn't be a problem:

```
@Target(ElementType.FIELD)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Constraint(validatedBy = NotEmptyFieldsValidator.class)
public @interface NotEmptyFields {

    String message() default "List cannot contain empty fields";

    Class<?>[] groups() default {};

    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};

}


public class NotEmptyFieldsValidator implements ConstraintValidator<NotEmptyFields, List<String>> {

    @Override
    public void initialize(NotEmptyFields notEmptyFields) {
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isValid(List<String> objects, ConstraintValidatorContext context) {
        return objects.stream().allMatch(nef -> nef != null && !nef.trim().isEmpty());
    }

}
```

Usage? Simple:

```
class QuestionPaper{

    @NotEmptyFields
    private List<String> questionIds;
    // getters and setters
}
```

P.S. Didn't test the logic, but I guess it's good.

Comment: The validation looks like it would crash on `nef==null`

Comment: I edit the code like below and it works perfect:
    @Override
    public boolean isValid(List<String> objects, ConstraintValidatorContext context) {
        if (objects == null || objects.isEmpty())
            return false;
        return objects.stream().allMatch(nef -> nef != null && !nef.trim().isEmpty());
    }

Comment: Overengineering I guess. You can simply use the already existing annotations.

Answer (score 20):

I just had similar case to solve

```
class QuestionPaper {

    @NotEmpty
    private List<@NotBlank String> questionIds;

    // getters and setters
}
```

Comment: It actually triggers an error 500 that can't be handled. "org.springframework.beans.NotReadablePropertyException". Example of message: "JSR-303 validated property XYZ does not have a corresponding accessor for Spring data binding - check your DataBinder's configuration (bean property versus direct field access)"

Comment: Correcting my own comment. It actually works. But, to do this answer in a proper way, you need BEFORE do this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44064198/10746857.

Comment: It works out of the box for me with the latest Spring boot (3.0.2) with Graphql

Answer (score 5):

These might suffice the need, if it is only on null or empty space.

`@NotNull, @Valid, @NotEmpty`

You can check with [example](https://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-3-mvc-and-jsr303-valid-example/). Complete set of [validations - JSR 303](http://beanvalidation.org/1.0/spec/) give an idea which suits the requirement.

Comment: I have already tried, but these are not recursively applied to the list elements, rather it is enforced to the list. Thanks for the reply though. :)

Answer (score 4):

If List is of Integers, then go as below

```
class QuestionPaper {

    @NotEmpty
    private List<@Min(0) Integer> questionIds;

    // getters and setters
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
!CollectionUtils.isEmpty(questionIds) 
   && !questionIds.stream.anyMatch(StringUtils::isEmpty())
```

Comment: This also seems to work,  List<String> questionIds = Arrays.asList("1000", "", " ");
  if (!questionIds.contains(null) && !questionIds.contains("")) {
   System.out.println("Valid List !!!!");
  } else {
   System.out.println("Invalid List!!!!");
  } My concern is how to add this to spring validator.

Comment: I am not sure whether or not Bean Validation works on references

Answer (score 0):

This can easily be addressed if you use

```
import org.apache.commons.collections.CollectionUtils;

    QuestionPaper question = new QuestionPaper();
    question.setQuestionIds(Arrays.asList("", " ", "10103"));

   if(CollectionUtils.isNotEmpty(question.getQuestionIds())) {
        // proceed
    } else {
        //throw exception or return
    }
```

This will check for nontnull and notempty.