# Can List<String> values be validated using JSR 303 field validations

Tags: java, spring, bean-validation

I am validating a bean with JSR 303 specifications, it has a parameter that contains list of string. I want to validate each string in this list as this is the request object. I already have a pattern for matching each string, but i am not able to apply if recursively for each entry in the list.

```
@NotEmpty(message = "phoneNumber must not be null or empty")
@Valid @Pattern(regexp = REGEX_PHONENUMBER, message = "Not a valid phoneNumber")
private List<String> phoneNumber;
```

Comment: Yes you can validate `List<String>` but you need to create custom validator. Please see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39504205/spring-validate-list-of-strings-for-non-empty-elements

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A custom validator need to be implemented to make it possible using JSR 303

```
@PhoneNumbers
private List<String> phoneNumber;
```

It's supported out of the box in Bean Validation 2.0 / JSR 380:

```
List<@NotEmpty @Pattern(regexp = REGEX_PHONENUMBER) String>
```

Comment: Thanks used a custom validator, could not try second method as it is not supported by project.